# Alpine Linux run a startup script to change the /etc/issue

Tags: shell-script, startup, alpine-linux

I have done the following shell script that update the `/etc/issue` with the current ip's of all non-loopback interfaces:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "You can use one of the following ip addresses in order to look the page or even ssh into the machine" > /etc/issue
ip -4 -o addr show up  scope global | awk '{print $2,":",$4}'| sed -e "s/\/[1-9]*//" >> /etc/issue
```

Now I want to make it run at boot in order to update the `/etc/issue` with the network ips. Over Debian-based distros I would place it over `/etc/rc.local` but alpine does not have this file. How I will make this script to run in an equivalent way of `/etc/rc.local`?

## Edit 1

I tried to put it on `/etc/local.d` but it failed to change properly the `/etc/issue`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to enable `local.d` scripts at boot time:

```
rc-update add local default
```

Then just place your script into `/etc/local.d/UpdateIssue.start` and make it executable.

You can find more details about `local.d` scripts in OpenRC on Gentoo wiki:

https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki//etc/local.d

Comment: See also https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Writing_Init_Scripts